# rss feed xml ISO-8859-7 encoding shows greek characters as question marks

Tags: php, xml, encoding, utf-8, rss

Using php to generate a xml rss feed.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8");

$rssfeed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$rssfeed .= '<rss version="2.0">';
$rssfeed .= '<channel>';
$rssfeed .= '<title>Events on Spotlight | StudentLife.com.cy</title>';
$rssfeed .= '<link>http://spotlight.studentlife.com.cy</link>';
$rssfeed .= '<description>All the events that student may be interested in.</description>';
$rssfeed .= '<language>en-us</language>';
$rssfeed .= '<copyright>Copyright (C) 2014 studentlife.com.cy</copyright>';

$today= strtotime("now");
$today=date('Y-m-d',$today);
$later= strtotime("+1 week");
$later=date('Y-m-d',$later);


$db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
if (!$db) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($db_name,$db);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT p.ID,  m1.meta_value as event_address, m2.meta_value as event_date, p.post_title,p.guid as link
from events_posts p
inner join events_postmeta m1
on p.ID=m1.post_id and p.post_type='event' and (p.post_status='publish' or p.post_status='recurring') 
and m1.meta_key='address'
inner join events_postmeta m2
on p.ID=m2.post_id and p.post_type='event' and (p.post_status='publish' or p.post_status='recurring') 
and m2.meta_key='st_date'
and m2.meta_value between '".$today."' and '".$later."'
order by p.ID", $db);


  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        extract($row);

        $rssfeed .= '<item>';
        $rssfeed .= '<title>' . $post_title . '</title>';
        $rssfeed .= '<description>' . $event_address . '</description>';
    $rssfeed .= '<link>' . $link . '</link>';
        $rssfeed .= '<pubDate>' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s O", strtotime($event_date)) . '</pubDate>';
        $rssfeed .= '</item>';
    }

$rssfeed .= '</channel>';
$rssfeed .= '</rss>';

mysql_close($db);

$rssfeed=preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $rssfeed);



$fp = fopen("rss.xml","wb");
fwrite($fp,$rssfeed);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

The encoding in my database is utf8_bin. You can execute the file at http://studentlife.com.cy/cron.php and see the results at http://studentlife.com.cy/rss.xml.

The xml gives me an encoding error

Comment: You say the browser that you response/the xml is in this charset. That does not mean that the strings you output are really encoded that way.

Comment: So shall I dig through my database to find the encoding of the string?

Comment: The encoding of the database connection would be the first place to look. But if ever possible use UTF-8 in your scripts and only if you need to output a different charset, convert the data in the last possible moment. Unicode can contain a lot more characters then ANSI charsets.

Comment: The encoding of my database is **utf8_bin**. I edit my post and attach my php code for you to see.

Comment: The database connection encoding does not depend on the encoding of the database schema or fields. Think about it, even different fields in the same table can have different charset/encoding options. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Set the connection encoding to utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank [ThW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2265374/thw) for his comments. The solutions is to connect to your database using mysqli then se the charset to UTF-8 using

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
```

mysqli_set_charset () sets the default character set to be used when sending data from and to the database server.

See [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)